# Uniqueness of a measure extension as a corollary

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite premeasure on a semiring $S$ and $\nu$ the outer measure generated by it.

Supposing I know that for each extension $\nu'$ of $\nu\big|_{\sigma(S)}$, that has the property that it is complete, $\nu'$ also has to be an extension of $\nu\big|_{\mathcal{M}}$, where $\mathcal{M}\supseteq \sigma(S)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of $\nu$-measurable sets, how do I prove that $\nu\big|_{\mathcal{M}}$ is the only extension of $\nu\big|_{\sigma(S)}$ (and also of $\mu$) to a measure on $\mathcal{M}$ ?

---

*My progress on this (optional reading):* Suppose there exists  a measure $\eta:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ different from $\nu\big|_{\mathcal{M}}$. Then $\eta$ can't be complete (by the above assumption), so there has to be a set $Y\in \mathcal{M}$ that has measure $0$ with respect to $\eta$, but contains a subset $Z$, that is not measurable with $\eta$, i.e. $Z\not\in\mathcal{M}$. Then $\nu\big|_{\mathcal{M}}(Y)$ has to be different from $0$ since it is known that $\nu\big|_{\mathcal{M}}$ is a complete measurable (so if $\nu\big|_{\mathcal{M}}(Y)$ were $0$ by completeness that would imply $Z\in\mathcal{M}$ and that would be a contradiction). Since $\eta$ and $\nu\big|_{\mathcal{M}}$ are both extensions of $\nu\big|_{\sigma(S)}$ (resp. $\mu:S\rightarrow [0,\infty]$) and they don't agree on $Y$, we obtain $Y\in\mathcal{M}\setminus\sigma(S)$ (resp. $Y\in\mathcal{M}\setminus S$).

Comment: Have a look at Theorem 1.14 in Folland's Real Analysis (http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Real_analysis.html?id=uPkYAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: I haven't read the optional reading yet. Folland's results are about premeasures on algebras, not semirings. What you want can be found in C.Swartz, Measure, Integration and Function Spaces (World Scientific,1994), p.44-46, Lemma 11, Theorem 12,Example 13,Theorem 14,Remark 15 and, maybe, Remark 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\eta: \mathcal{M} \to [0, \infty]$ be an extension of $\nu\big|_{\sigma(S)}$ and let $\eta': \mathcal{M'} \to [0, \infty]$ be its completion.

Then $\eta'$
is a complete extension of $\nu\big|_{\sigma(S)}$, therefore $\eta = \eta'\big|_\mathcal{M} = \nu\big|_\mathcal{M}$